# Identify users pc/internet has authority to login?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ip

I am building a CRM website in which i want to restrict user login from outside the company premises. For this purpose I need to identify the user PC while any one login in my CRM website. I have an idea that check all user ip during log-in but we have dynamic IP in our company when we restart our internet connection then our internet IP will be change every time, Issues I have are stated below:

1. Cookies can be cleared, and vary form browser to browser
2. Most of the users don't have a dedicated public IP, and their IP keeps on changing for every session
3. a combo of cookies and IP might also not serve the purpose

So which technique shall I use to implement it or there is any other method for it ?

The language I am using for this is PHP-jquery-mysql

[image]

Comment: Would this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999175/php-how-to-check-if-the-client-is-local

Comment: but my IP keeps on changing , how i track next time ?

Answer (score 0):

its just an Idea, have you try to get there location by HTML5 Geolocation it should give you similar numbers Latitude and Longitude,

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
</script>
```

hope it helps [Demo](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

Comment: i also want to give  access to some users from there home laptops. so location can't help me out

Comment: by the way if you forward the static(public) IP or public domain(domain.com) to your server(where CRM app located). every one in your office will seeing with same IP (according to their gateway). hope this was a good hint.

Comment: i mean , i also want to provide access to some special users from  outside the company (from there home). how could i forward the static ip to my server. could you explain it ?

Comment: Network/System Administrator usually do this part, they usually redirect IP(s) that ISP providing to them through router and its not only that there should be protection(Firewall rules) to limit the valid ports/Protocols(80,443,..)