# How to find out a http request is sent by a local network computer or by an internet client?

Tags: java, servlets, ip, httprequest, subnet

I need a structure which check if a request is sent by a local network computer or is sent by a remote client via internet.

Is it possible to get this using httprequest object or ip address?

```
IF client is a local network computer
  DO 1
IF Client is a remote computer from internet
  DO 2
```

Comment: You can check for the reverse proxy's IP for internet requests.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999175/php-how-to-check-if-the-client-is-local][1] Check if it resolved your problem

Comment: @Rishaldevsingh thanks, I knew that but I was looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the HttpServletRequest you can look at the

```
request.getRemoteAddr() 
request.getLocalAddr()
```

These can be used to determine where the client request came from.

@See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html